# How to export runnable JAR file to runnable OS X file?

Tags: java, macos, jar, export

I would like to ask how can I export **runnable JAR file to runnable OS X** file. I made it work by creating *.app* but I found out that there is no problem with getting in the resource files and all the java classes using any archiving software (I don't want someone to read my code.).

Does anyone have some experiences or idea about this?

I am using Netbeans IDE. Just... for information.

Comment: You might want to look at "obfuscator", which can "scramble" the `.class` files so it's hard to reverse engineer. Depending on how you're doing it, you could use a `.app` wrapper which wrapped the Jar file itself, which would make it a little more difficult.  At the end of the day, it's near impossible to stop one who is  determined from gaining access to your resources

Comment: If there's no other way, then thank you.

Comment: None that I'm aware off. You could choose to encode your resources and decode them as you load them internally, but there is an overhead involved in doing that